# Trying to install software, it says there is no available space, but there is

Tags: linux, debian, apt

I think I am doing something wrong.

I'm trying to install gparted on Debian:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

It says that it can't create "/var/lib/dpkg/updates/tmp.i" because there is no available space on the device (it tries to allocate ~5MB of disk space. But when I do:

```
df -h /var/lib
```

It says:

```
/dev/sda6             2,8G  1,4G  1,3G  52% /var
```

That is I have 1.3GB free disk space out there, isn't it?

So what is going on here?

BTW, I have now two problems related to this, the first one is this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87403/mysqld-cant-start-without-any-info 
So it's really important for me to find out what's going on, please...

Comment: Did you recently delete files to make up space?

Comment: Yes, I had ~1.2GB of free space, then deleted ~100MB so now I have ~1.3GB

Comment: Did you try `df -i`?

Comment: Michael, this show available: 0, does it show nodes or something? If so, then what can I do about it?

Comment: Delete or archive files. You have too many "small" files.

Comment: OK, but which ones? I have no idea...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15221702 : there you can find a way to count the number of files for each of your directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as pointed out by Michael Hampton, the issue is that you are running out of inodes for this partition.

Some solutions exist :

- Free up some of these, it's up to you to choose which files can be moved/deleted depending on how important they are.
- If you can't move/delete files and you are using LVM, try to expand the logical volume size : it will increase the amount of inodes available.
- If you can't move/delete files and that the LVM expand would happen often, think about migrating to a filesystem that dynamically allocates inodes like XFS but keep in mind that it may lead to fragmentation.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this type of behavior while working on VM's where the host is actually out of disk space to support the guest.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the case - i'm connecting with a server directly with putty.

Comment: Maybe this could be helpful: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7950/reserved-space-for-root-on-a-filesystem-why